# web crawler loop with a limit of 1000 parallel https requests only process between 100 and 200 requests within a minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am writing a web crawler in Node js with the request module and redis as url cache.
What I try to accomplish is a constantly crawler loop (endlessly) which gets a url from redis and makes a https request.

I have tried to add paralell requests limitation. For example 10 parallel requests.
I do not know why but no matter if I choose 10 or 1000 the outcome is always the same.
Within one minute only between 100 and 200 requests get processed.

Please give me a hint where am I doing wrong. I would like to process 60.000 requests (urls) per minute, but even if I choose 10k parallel requests as limit it process only between 100 and 200 requests within a minute.

My code as below:

**the crawler loop:**

```
var limit   = 1000;       // parallel requests limit
var running = 0;  

function loop() {
  while(running < limit) {
    req(function(){
      running--;
      loop();
    });  
    running++;
  }
}
loop();
```

**and the req function to make the https requests to the urls given by redis:**

```
  function req (callback){ 
    client.select(2);
    client.RANDOMKEY([], function (err, result) {
    var url = result;
    client.del(url);

    if(err) { 
      return  callback();
    }
    else if (url == null || url == "" ) {
      return  callback();
    } 
    else {
      request(url,function(error, response, body){
        return callback();
      });
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: "I would like to process 60.000 requests (urls) per minute" - this is something that you cannot guarantee and it depends on many things, e.g. the time it takes to crawl the website, the time it takes to make a network request, etc. The "100 and 200 requests within a minute" you're seeing is most likely your limit. Also, there's no such thing as "parallel" in `Node.js` - you should look into how `asynchronous` calls work in `Node.js`.

Comment: I can't believe that Node js is only capable of max 3 concurrent https get requests per second ... there must be an issue in my code or another better solution

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You're totally disregarding the fact that each call has to go over the wire and come back with some result and the time that it takes for each request will depend on your network, how fast the website responds, etc... You can't just say I want to crawl 60k requests per minute without having a good idea of what the actual bottleneck is. It could be a lot of things, and with what you've presented it's impossible to say how to "speed up" your crawler.

Comment: Well... what do you need to work with and give me a hint how to speed it up ...what would be your approach ? I do understand that each htttps call takes on average 2 seconds. But if there is no other solution googles index would be very small nowadays.

Comment: If you know that on average it takes 2 seconds to make an HTTP request from your `Node.js` program then when are you getting the "60.000 requests per minute" requirement? That's 1,000 requests per second but you just said each call takes about 2 second. Google has years of experience crawling the web and an enormous amount of computing power, so I suggest you add more network bandwidth and more computing power to your setup and see if you're seeing any improvements. There's nothing in your code you can do to get those numbers you're asking - it will be limited by a lot of factors.